# how to make effect pull from top to bottom 1 page like android title bar use css3

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a effect in html look like the effect pull title bar from top to bottom in android.

Anyone have an idea how to do it? Or what tool i need?

When I swipe, the page just shows follow animation but does not follow my finger

I am newbie. Plsease help me.

Thanks for reading!!!

This is my css i try:

```
.myanimation {
      animation : mymove .3s linear;
      -webkit-animation : mymove .3s linear;
}
.removeanimation {
    animation : remove .3s linear;
    -webkit-animation : remove .3s linear;
}
@keyframes mymove
{
    0%   {width: 20%;}
    25%  {width: 40%;}
    50%  {width: 60%;}
    75%  {width: 80%;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /*Safari and Chrome*/
{
    0%   {width: 20%;}
    25%  {width: 40%;}
    50%  {width: 60%;}
    75%  {width: 80%;}
    100% {width: 100%;}
}
@keyframes remove
{
    0%   {width: 100%;}
    25%  {width: 80%;}
    50%  {width: 60%;}
    75%  {width: 40%;}
    100% {width: 20%;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes remove /*Safari and Chrome*/
{
    0%   {width: 100%;}
    25%  {width: 80%;}
    50%  {width: 60%;}
    75%  {width: 40%;}
    100% {width: 20%;}
}
```

this is javascript (i use hammer.js):

```
$(".play").hammer().on("swiperight", function (event) {
        $('#mainSetting').removeClass('hide');
        $('#mainSetting').removeClass('removeanimation');
        $('#mainSetting').addClass('myanimation');
        $('#mainSetting').css("width","100%");
    });

    $("#mainSetting").hammer().on("swipeleft", function(event) {
            $('#mainSetting').removeClass('myanimation');
            $('#mainSetting').addClass('removeanimation');
            $('#mainSetting').css("width","10%");
            setTimeout(function(){$('#mainSetting').addClass('hide')},400);
    });
```

Comment: Post what you had tried

Comment: I updated what i try. but that not like effect in android

Comment: Not sure what part of this you are having trouble with, but you don't need to use the animations like that at all. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9Cq8/). Using simply transitions would be more accessible. If that isn't what you meant, then showing an example would be good..

Comment: Thanks for your respond. Actualy i do like you do. but i need when i touch the screen and pull down, the page pull down follow my finger, same with up. that i dont know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested, but combined with the fiddle, you would simple replace the jQuery for opening and closing on click with the hammer.js implementation. It would be something like this:

```
var animate = $('.animate');

var hammeropen = Hammer(element).on("swipedown", function(event) {
    $('animate').addClass('open');
});

var hammerclose = Hammer(element).on("swipeup", function(event) {
    $('animate').removeClass('open');
});
```

At least according to the hammer.js documentation.

For the CSS, you would just need this for the item you want to act like the android top bar that slides from top down:

```
.animate {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background:#333;
    top:0;
    bottom:90%;
    max-height:20px;
    transition:all 0.5s ease;
    z-index:2;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
}

.animate.open {
    bottom:0;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but this is like i did. when swipe page just show follow animation but not follow my finger. :(

Comment: Ahhhh. Didn't realize that is what you were asking for -- will see if I can find an answer to that.